# R, Python, rpy2 and drc package in Docker

Tags: python, r, docker, conda, rpy2

I'm trying to build a docker image to execute a python proces which calls (with rpy2) the package **drc** from R.

I'm using a **amazonlinux** docker image and to use **drc** I have de following lines to install it via conda:

```
RUN conda install -c r rpy2=2.9.4 --yes
RUN conda install -c conda-forge r-drc=3.0_1 --yes
```

With the image build I enter into a running container with:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint bash mydockerName
```

And when I enter to R via `R` it throws me the next error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'utils':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:
  call: system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)
  error: error in running command
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'stats':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:
  call: system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)
  error: error in running command
During startup - Warning messages:
1: package 'utils' in options("defaultPackages") was not found
2: package 'stats' in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

I've been googling the last days and I'm out of possible solutions...

Many thanks!

Xevi

Comment: I am having a similar problem with R, but on a different container type. I suspect the 'which' command may not be present in your docker image. For zsh this is a builtin, while other shells expect it to be in /usr/bin. Alternatively it might have 'which' but can't find some other sytem tool it expects. So far I have not been able to figure out what system tools are visible to R when it loads a library or what utils expects to find on the system.

Answer (score 0):

The rpy2 project has images that could constitute a starting point. `conda` is not used though.
https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2-docker

If `conda` is needed, look at the images managed by the jupyter project for example.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem in a different container type by installing 'which'. This package is often omitted from linux enviroments because there are "better" alternatives. However, R package writers often still depend on 'which'. So figure out how to install [this](https://carlowood.github.io/which/) in your container and it may fix the issue.